# Add foreign key relationship on the existing table

Tags: django

I have two models A and B in my django app but,  they have don't have relationship between them.  I want to add one to many relationship between them. How to add this relationship without loosing the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from django.db import models

class A(models.Model):
    # if B is foreign in A
    some_field_of_B = models.ForeignKey(A, on_delete=PROTECT, null=True)

# or

class B(models.Model):
    # if A is foreign in B
    some_field_of_A= models.ForeignKey(B, on_delete=PROTECT, null=True)
```

you can also specify on_delete to SET_NULL or SET_DEFAULT depending upon your needs.

Refer: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete

Comment: I would like to add that based on already exists records, foreign key should be added as nullable, then apply a data migration to populate the history, and at the end if you need, you can set the foreign key as not nullable, depends of your needs